# Server error says request exceeds MaxRequestLen

Tags: apache-2.2, php5, upload

I have this issue and I know I need to increase the:

```
   FcgidMaxRequestLen 15728640
```

I have tried to do this on the htaccess page, but when uploading, the whole site gives me the 500 Internal error.

The error is:

```
  [Thu Mar 07 06:16:05 2013] [warn] [client ???????] mod_fcgid: HTTP request length 16783183 (so far) exceeds MaxRequestLen (16777216), referer:
```

I then have tried adding:

```
 <IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
 FcgidMaxRequestLen 15728640
 </IfModule>
```

This still causes my server to display a 500 error.

What am I doing wrong? I am using a MT DV4 server, I have ssh into it, and the field is saying:

```
  FcgidIdleTimeout 40
  FcgidMaxRequestLen 1073741824
  FcgidProcessLifeTime 30
  FcgidMaxProcesses 20
  FcgidMaxProcessesPerClass 8
  FcgidMinProcessesPerClass 0
  FcgidConnectTimeout 30
  FcgidIOTimeout 45
  FcgidInitialEnv RAILS_ENV production
  FcgidIdleScanInterval 10
```

So for some reason its set to a 1gb and I think shoud be ok?

Answer (score 1):

Well many thanks to this page for the extra information that helped:

[The Full Process Here](http://stuffthatspins.com/2013/01/22/exceeds-maxrequestlen-16777216-plesk-mod_fcgid-unable-to-upload-large-files/)

All i was missing with all the other sites and pages i viewed was the last bit.

> Let’s reconfigure your domain with Plesk....

```
  /usr/local/psa/admin/bin/httpdmng  --reconfigure-domain yourdomain.com
```

then

```
 % service apache2 restart
 % service psa restart
```

mainly the psa reconfigure and then psa restart